Does the infinite power tower $\left(e^{1/e} + \frac{1}{1^s}\right)^{\left(e^{1/e} + \frac{1}{2^s}\right)^{\cdots}}$converge?
I am studying the convergence of the infinite power tower:
$
\left(e^{1/e} + \frac{1}{1^s}\right)^{\left(e^{1/e} + \frac{1}{2^s}\right)^{\left(e^{1/e} + \frac{1}{3^s}\right)^{\cdots}}}
$
It is known that $e^{1/e}$ is the upper bound of convergence for the power tower $ a^{a^{a^{a^{\cdots}}}} $, and when $ a = e^{1/e} $, the infinite power tower equals $ e$. Based on this, I hypothesize that the given tower converges for $s \geq 1 $.
Could someone provide insights, proofs, or references regarding the convergence properties of this power tower?

Don't you fear the fall of such a "tower-like" formula ?

It converges if and only if $s>2$. Gennady Bachman analyzed this type of question quite thoroughly in his 1995 paper Convergence of Infinite Expoenentials. If $e^{1/e} \le a_n < e^{1/e}(1+\frac{1}{2e n^2})$, then $$
a_1, a_1^{a_2}, a_1^{a_2^{a_3}},\dots
$$
converges. Conversely, if $a_n > e^{1/e}(1+\frac{1}{2e n^2})$, the power tower diverges. The paper is free to download if you want to read the details.

Thank you very much.
